# How to proof $\text{inf}( \lambda A )= \lambda \text{inf} A$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R, \lambda \ge 0, \quad \lambda A := \{\lambda x: x \in A\}$

How to proof $\text{inf} \lambda A = \lambda \text{inf} A$?

I have tried to do it with a direct proof like that:

$$\text{inf} \lambda A = \exists c \in \mathbb R, \forall a \in \lambda A : c \le a_{\lambda}$$
$$\equiv \exists c \in \mathbb R, \lambda \in \mathbb R, \forall a \in A: c \le \lambda a $$

**Note**: I think that I have understood whyt it should be $\text{inf} \lambda A = \lambda \text{inf} A$ intuitively. But unfortunately I am not able to really finish that proof.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: there is the command `\inf` which you should use instead of `\text{inf}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda = 0$ that is trivial. If it is not, you have
$$\lambda \inf A \leq \lambda x, \quad \forall x \in A. (*)$$
Now fix $\varepsilon > 0$. By definition of $\inf A$ you know that you can find $\bar{x} \in A$ such that 
$$\inf A \leq \bar{x} < \inf A + \varepsilon.$$
Multiply by $\lambda$ (which is positive, so the inequalities do not change):
$$\lambda \inf A \leq \lambda \bar{x} < \lambda \inf A + \lambda \varepsilon = \lambda \inf A + \varepsilon' (**)$$
where $\varepsilon'$ is an arbitrary positive number. (*) and (**) give you that 
$$\lambda \inf A = \inf \lambda A.$$

Comment: Can you explain your conclusion from (\*) and (**) more detailed, please?

Comment: $(*)$ and $(**)$ say exactly that $\lambda \inf A$ is $\inf \lambda A$. Set $l = \lambda \inf A$ for simplicity. Then 
$l \leq \lambda x$ for all $x \in A$ and for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you find $\lambda \bar{x} \in \lambda A$ such that 
$l < \lambda \bar{x} < l+\varepsilon$. 
These two conditions are exactly the definition of $\inf \lambda A$. Let me know if you see it.

Comment: I am sorry but I think I still do not understand the last conclusion fully. If you think there is something you can make more clear I will appreciate that. Basically I do not see why $\leq$ changes to $=$

Comment: So, in general $l = \inf B$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ if two conditions are satisfied: 

$(*)$ $l \leq y, \forall y \in B$
$(**)$ $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ you can find $x \in B$ such that $l \leq x < l+\varepsilon$.

In my answer, I have shown these two conditions are met, where $B = \lambda A$ and $l = \lambda \inf A$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $\ell=\inf \lambda A$. Prove (using the definition) that $\inf A=\frac{\ell}{\lambda }$.

Answer (score 0):

If $l=\inf A$ then by definition $x\leq l$ and consequently $\lambda x\leq\lambda l$ for each $x\in A$.

This means that $\lambda l$ is an upperbound of $\lambda A:=\{\lambda x\mid x\in A\}$.

Now it remains to prove that $\lambda l$ is the least upperbound of $\lambda A$.

Let us assume now that it is **not** the least upperbound of $\lambda A$, so that finding a contradiction is enough.

Some $x\in A$ must exist with: $$\lambda l<\lambda x\tag1$$

This cannot be true if $\lambda=0$ and combined with the knowledge that $\lambda\geq0$ we conclude that $\lambda>0$.

Then we can divide both sides of $(1)$ by $\lambda$ and the inequality will stay valid:$$l< x\tag2$$

However $(2)$ contradicts that $l=\inf A$, and we are ready.

Answer (score 0):

assume lambda does not vanish

Then $$\lambda \inf A \leq \lambda x, \quad \forall x \in A. $$

that is 
$$\lambda \inf A \leq y, \quad \forall y\in \lambda A$$
Hence.
$$\lambda \inf A \leq \inf(\lambda A. )$$ the same reasoning hold if you set $B =\lambda A$ then $A=\lambda^{-1}B$ then we have 
$$\lambda^{-1} \inf B \leq \inf(\lambda^{-1} B )$$

that is 
$$\lambda \inf A \geq \inf(\lambda A. )$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get from $$\lambda^{-1} \inf B \leq \inf(\lambda^{-1} B )$$  to
$$\lambda \inf A \geq \inf(\lambda A. )$$ ?
If I write $$\lambda^{-1} \inf B \leq \inf(\lambda^{-1} B )$$ and put in $B = \lambda A $ I am not getting your last line